# Android Kotlin: running a recursive function with an interval within the broadcast receiver is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am building an Android application. In my app, I need to run a task in the background even when the app is closed every 15 seconds or so. I am using Broadcast receiver for that.

This is my broadcast receiver.

```
class RegisterReceiversScheduler: BroadcastReceiver() {
    private lateinit var handler: Handler
    private lateinit var context: Context

    private fun getHandler(): Handler {
        if (! this::handler.isInitialized) {
            this.handler = Handler();
        }

        return this.handler
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        this.context = context as Context
        registerReceivers()
    }

    private fun registerReceivers() {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "I am here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        getHandler().postDelayed({
            this.registerReceivers()
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

As you can see I am toasting a message every five seconds.

This is how I register the broadcast receiver in my activity.

```
var registerReceiversFilter = IntentFilter()
        registerReceiversFilter.addAction("com.forkthecoup.com22222.RegisterReceiversScheduler")
        var registerReceivers = RegisterReceiversScheduler();
        registerReceiver(registerReceivers, registerReceiversFilter)
```

I added this in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<receiver android:name=".RegisterReceiversScheduler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.forkthecoup.com22222.RegisterReceiversScheduler" ></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

When I run the app, it is not toasting any message. Then I check in the logcat and I see the following error.

```
2021-02-25 15:42:04.628 13463-13463/com.forkthecoop.com22222 E/ActivityThread: Activity com.forkthecoop.com22222.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.forkthecoop.com22222.RegisterReceiversScheduler@3e221d4 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.forkthecoop.com22222.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.forkthecoop.com22222.RegisterReceiversScheduler@3e221d4 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1594)
```

The error is basically saying that the receiver has already been registered. If that is the case, I should at least see the toast message once. But I am not seeing it. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Broadcast receivers are not meant for doing background things. For this, You can use Services in Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreground service to achieve this functionality.
https://medium.com/@jayd1992/foreground-services-in-android-e131a863a33d

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code (but it totally violates Android guidelines about recurring tasks). Are you sending broadcast the Intent that will trigger your Receiver?

After your `registerReceiver` method, you can try with this:

`sendBroadcast(Intent("com.forkthecoup.com22222.RegisterReceiversScheduler"))`

Also, I'd suggest you to init the handler this way:

```
private val handler by lazy { Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) }
```

and clean the `getHandler()` method

By the way this answers your question but if Android system decides to kill your app, it will kill it anyway